# Normalized versus un-normalized histogram: how to convert from first to another in python? And what happens to chi squared?

Tags: python, statistics, histogram, curve-fitting

Hi I have the following set of code for an unnormalized histogram:

```
def vmag_hist_maxwell(vel_bin_size,vmag):
    plt.ioff()
    maxwell = stats.maxwell
    params = maxwell.fit(vmag, floc=0)
    max_bin = int(np.max(vmag)/vel_bin_size) + 2
    bins_re= np.array([n*vel_bin_size for n in range(0,max_bin)])
    xmax = 1000
    plt.xlim(0,xmax)
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(vmag, bins_re, histtype = 'bar', facecolor='blue', normed = 1)  #n = counts, bins = bin locations, patches = ?
    bins_m = [(bins_re[i]+bins_re[i+1])/2.0 for i in range(0,len(bins_re)-1)]
    y_fit = maxwell.pdf(bins_m, *params)
    x_points = np.arange(0,xmax)
    y_fit_smooth = maxwell.pdf(x_points, *params)
    plt.plot(x_points, y_fit_smooth, lw=2, color = 'red')
    chi_sq = stats.chisquare(n, y_fit)
    plt.title("Velocity Histogram GB size  %0.1f;   chi_sq:  %0.2e   ;   p_val:   %0.2e   ;   vel_binwidth:  %0.2s   ;   sigma:  %0.1f"  % (R, chi_sq[0], chi_sq[1],vel_bin_size, params[1]), size = 8)         #Sets title
    plt.xlabel("Velocity magnitude in km/s", size = 10)                 #Sets title
    plt.ylabel("Normalized histogram with maxwellian fit", size = 10)       #Sets title
    filename = plot_file_loc+"velocity_fitted_hist_gb_"+str(int(R))+ "_vel_binwidth_"+ str(int(vel_bin_size)) +"_lasdamas" + ".png" 
    plt.savefig(filename , dpi=200)
    plt.close()
```

This produces the following plot:
[image]

Then, I make the following changes in the code shown above:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(vmag, bins_re, histtype = 'bar', facecolor='blue', normed = 0)      
#Here I have changed normed = 1 to normed = 0
#I also make the following two changes:
y_fit = 41000*vel_bin_size*maxwell.pdf(bins_m, *params)
y_fit_smooth = 41000*vel_bin_size*maxwell.pdf(x_points, *params)
#Here 41000 is the total number of points in the histogram
#And vel_bin_size is the binwidth
```

This generates the following picture:
[image]

Is this the right way to un-normalize a histogram and do a fit on an un-normalized histogram?
As you can notice, the chi squared and p-value have changed drastically! Is this to be expected??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on your code, but it seems to work. Note that the chi-square goodness-of-fit test is designed to work on *counts* of data falling within each bin. You *cannot* use it on normalized values, or with any other scaling, in fact. So whatever you show, the chi-square has to be based on the actual counts.